# With page load speed being a ranking factor, what speed optimizations do you recommend to prioritize?

Tags: apache2, optimization, load-time

My website has been becoming slow somewhere during development, according to visitors who emailed me, what speed optimizations do you recommend to priotize? Caching? CDN? Any input is very appriciated! The server is running Ubuntu 14.10 with Apache vlatest and PHP 7.

Comment: Keep in mind the user complaints may have nothing to do with your site. The internet is elastic and can give very different results per user, day by day, and even minute by minute. It is best to start with a waterfall report from your browser such as chrome as close to your server as is reasonable over a period of time. This will give you good data and a clear clue what to work on. If your site works well for you, your users can do the same to give you solid clues as to what may be going on.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to figure out what to optimize and what the priorities are, I suggest using GTMetrix or similar analysis tool (Pingdom, Google Pagespeed Insights) to get a report of what could be slowing your site down as well as suggestions on what to fix.

FWIW, GTMetrix gives your site very, very good scores. You may be worried about nothing.